# linking of uploaded file for python to use

Tags: javascript, python, html

do any of u guys know to link uploaded file to python?
like when

```
<form id="upload"><input type="file" id="fileSelect" accept=".xlsx, .xls, .csv"/>
```

to replace Sample.xlsx

```
book = openpyxl.load_workbook('Sample.xlsx')
```

Comment: Upload file to python?

Comment: @spangle to html table to be exact but the values is read by python